# Наследование java

Tags: java

Объясните пожалуйста для чего это, если мы создали класс `Animal`, потом `Cat extends Animal`, для чего создают объекты вида `Animal barsik = new Cat();`  если могли просто `Cat barsik = new Cat();`  и это разновидность полиморфизма, или только `override` полиморфизм?

Answer (score 2):

Напоминает диалог:

- **Боб:** у меня есть кот
- **Алиса:** О, у тебя есть животное?
- **Боб:** нет, у меня кот
- **Алиса:** ну он же кот - значит животное?
- **Боб:** эмм... это полиморфизм или абстракция?
- **Бабушка:** хватит уже, он Барсик и он член семьи!

**Update**

Надеялся, что поймете, но не судьба. Посему буду объяснять:

Судьба кота зависит от точки зрения (или если угодно от *Use Case*)

1. Для Боба, который собирается его тискать и гладить - кот безусловно `Cat`
2. Для Алисы, которая даже и не знала о его существовании - он еще один `Animal`
3. Для бабушки - он не просто кот, а конкретно  `barsik instanceof Cat`

Соответственно, когда вы пишете `Animal barsik=new Cat()` - это означает, что вы собираетесь дальше юзать кота как животное, вам достаточен уровень абстракции `Animal`. Но, если дальше у вас в коде начинаются операции типа: `(Cat )barsik` - значит что-то пошло не так... - вам таки нужен был уровень абстракции `Cat barsik=new Cat()`

Дальше больше - дальше начинается философия: *правильный прогер, всегда должен пользоваться максимальным уровнем абстракции* (обратите внимание, что я лично не совсем соглашаюсь с такой философией). Некоторые особо упоротые интервьюеры спецом заваливают несчастного претендента на куске кода типа:

```
 ArrayList<String> strings=new ArrayList<String>();
 for(String s: strings)
     System.out.println(s);
```

С вопросом - что в этом коде не так? Правильный ответ:

```
List<String> strings=new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s: strings)
   System.out.println(s);
```

Для переменной `strings` уровень `ArrayList<>` излишен, достаточно только интерфейса `List`

Comment: Вроде я не совсем бред написал, имею ввиду виртуальные методы, но не понимаю зачем и хотелось простой ответ на мой вопрос!

Comment: Ответ явно не содержит информацию, разъясняющую причины использования абстракций, вместо конкретных типов.

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Answer (score 1):

Если мы работает с этими объектами на уровне интерфейса, определённого в абстрактном классе `Animal`, то лучше объявлять соответствующую переменную или поле как `Animal`, чтобы не быть зависимым от конкретной её реализации, которую можно будет легко изменить в одном месте, не меняя весь остальной код, использующий `Animal`. Это и есть преимущество полиморфизма. Если же нам нужно вызывать какие-то методы, которые есть только у `Cat`, то нет другого выхода кроме как объявлять соответствующие переменные и поля конкретным классом `Cat` или же ввести ещё один абстрактный класс `Feline` (род кошачьих в биологии), с дополнительными методами, от которого `Cat` и будет наследовать. Таким образом цепочка наследования будет такой `Animal -> Feline -> Cat`.

Answer (score 1):

Если очень простым языком, то можно работать с котами класса Cat - заполнить ими массив (ArrayList), производить над ними свойственные котам действия (кормить, поить, вычесывать, водить к ветеринару).

В какой-то момент в вашем кошачьем царстве появляется, например, пара собак класса Dog. Можно, конечно, создать для них отдельный массив ArrayList и никогда не смешивать котов и собак.

Но есть и другой вариант - выделить общие черты кошек и собак в отдельный класс животного (Animal - кличка, возраст, метод покормить), от которого **наследовать** классы Cat и Dog (чтобы кличка, возраст и покормить были у обоих видов). А когда потребуется покормить всех животных, можно создать массив с классом их родителя ArrayList, в который прекрасно запишутся как кошки (new Cat()), так и собаки (new Dog()), у которых можно будет вызывать общие методы, не задумываясь кого ты конкретно кормишь.

Ответ на вопрос о том, наследование или полиморфизм - тут речь про наследование.